# Wordpress, use tag slug to find tag name and store it in a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, slug

By doing this:

```
if (has_tag( "my-tag-slug", $post )) { $postsTag = "my-tag-slug"; $tagImageFormat = ".jpg"; }
```

I get:

```
- a variable named $postsTag containing the string "my-tag-slug"

- a variable named $tagImageFormat containing the string ".jpg"
```

The name of the tag that has this slug is "My tag slug". How can I get the following:

```
- a variable named $postsTagName containing the string "My tag slug"
```

By using the slug I grabbed from the function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the slug, grabbed from the function, because *directly you cannot* "un-slug" the string with Wordpress build-in functions, actually what you see as a slug, is the `post_name`, stored inside the database (Wordpress internally sanitize the titles of all saved posts / pages / attachments / etc with `sanitize_title()` [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)).

However, you can use simple PHP string string manipulation and construct your `$postsTagName` variable as you want, for example:

```
<?php    
$postsTagName = str_replace('-', ' ', ucfirst(strtolower('my-tag-slug')));
//Now your variable will contain My tag slug
?>
```

The [PHP FIDDLE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZY4RS3) is here.

Notes: The above code simply [replace](http://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.str-replace.php) the dashes `-` from the string and [capitalize](https://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.ucfirst.php) the first character.